# Writing a good highlighting function

Tags: regex, qt

I'm trying to implement a "highlighting" function to enhance the search capability  in a project I’m working on. It is supposed to highlight (apply a css background-color span tag) all occurrences of a search term in a larger QString. Right now, matches to be highlighted are determined with the following Regexp:

```
QRegExp reg("(\\b)(" + term + ")(\\b)|(.,:;'\"\')");
```

The regexp is case-insensitive and will match all instances of "term" followed by a word boundary or a punctuation symbol.

Right now, the highlighting code is a simple QString::replace API call:

```
entry=entry.replace(reg,"<span style=\"background-color: " + color + "\">" + term  + "</span>");
```

This works but is still buggy; the most important problem is that it ignores case; If a match is "Apple" the highlighted term will say "apple". This is a problem if a match is the first word in a sentence.

To fix this bug I was thinking of breaking the long QString into a QStringList array and searching for regexp matches one slot at a time. Is there a better/faster way to handle this job or is that how I should do it?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but... I'm guessing you can't pass in a second parameter on construction of the ``QRegExp``, i.e. ``Qt::CaseSensitive``? (Or, it has no effect at least?)

Comment: Please note these aren't threads, these are questions. One question, one post.